# how to combine multi Observable<T> to Observable<List<T>> in Rxjava2

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a method,

```
Observable<String> uploadFile(File file);
```

then i implement method

```
Single<List<String>> uploadFile(List<file> files){
     return Observable.fromIterable(files).flatMap(file -> upLoadFile(context, file))
            .toList();
 }
```

but

input file1, file2, file3 output is List{file2, file1, file3}

How can I keep the files in the correct order?

Comment: Are the Observables returned from uploadFile Singles?

Comment: Use `concatMapEager` instead of `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve the order of the observables use [concatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) instead of flatMap

```
Single<List<String>> uploadFile(List<file> files){
     return Observable.fromIterable(files).concatMap(file -> 
            upLoadFile(context, file))
            .toList();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ouput of the flat map to be sorted, use the sorted() method.

```
Observable.fromIterable(files)flatMap(file -> upLoadFile(context, file))
        .sorted().toList();
```